# if char array split count is less than 2

Tags: c#

Is there a way of making an if statement for when the amount of arrays split is less than 2. Eg make something not work if it can only be split into one string.

```
 string variable = txt.Text;
 string[] strArr = variable.Split(
      new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: if (array.length < 2)

Comment: it says string does not contain definition for length

Comment: Post your code to get a proper answer

Comment: You never posted the statement that you had the error on.

Comment: I get an error when I use your if statement

Comment: post the If statement you are using........

Comment: dw I wrote it in wrong, works perfect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you as posted in above comments.

```
        string variable = txt.Text;
        string[] strArr = variable.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (strArr.Length < 2)
        {

        }
```